# Parsing Javascript In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I usually use Beautiful Soup to parse html that I need, but I came across some Javascript that I would like to get from [here](https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections).

```
 <script>
function Model(){
    this.players = [{".....data......:""}];...etc
```

I tried to load it like...

```
import json
scrape_url = "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections?date=2016-12-15"

result = json.loads(scrape_url)
```

But I get "No Json Can Be Decoded".  Not sure how to go about this.

Comment: As your tag says, you know you should be using `BeautifulSoup`, but then why is your code using `json.loads(URL)`? Please check `json` document, it does not do what you think it does

Comment: so you want to extract data from within the script? You would first need to isolate it I.E. get just the string `{".....data......:"}` then use that with `json.loads`

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri, I couldn't get it working with bs4

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen got it, thanks!

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen How can I specify that data area?

Comment: I didn't actually know how to do it (before reading Alex Hall's solution) but figured that comment may help other people (and you) understand what it is you wanted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can extract JSON from arbitrary text with the [jsonfinder](https://pypi.io/project/jsonfinder/) library:

```
from jsonfinder import jsonfinder
import requests

scrape_url = "https://swishanalytics.com/optimus/nba/daily-fantasy-projections?date=2016-12-15"
content = requests.get(scrape_url).text
for _, __, obj in jsonfinder(content, json_only=True):
    if (obj and
            isinstance(obj, list) and
            isinstance(obj[0], dict) and
            {'player_id', 'event_id', 'name'}.issubset(obj[0])
            ):
        break
else:
    raise ValueError('data not found')

# Now you can use obj
print(len(obj))
print(obj[0])
```

Comment: Works pretty fine :)